# surefire plugin output: "WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred"

Tags: maven, jacoco, maven-surefire-plugin, jacoco-maven-plugin, sonar-maven-plugin

I have the following plugins configured in my maven build:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        </plugin -->
```

Everything appears to be working fine, tests are run, code coverage is consumed by Sonar.

If I uncomment the surefire plugin, Sonar does not consume the code coverage and I get a .dumpstream file with the below content.  What is causing this, and how do I resolve it?

> ## Created at 2019-11-13T19:35:46.185 WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
>
> ## Created at 2019-11-13T19:35:46.193 WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector
>
> (file:/C:/Users/tgunter/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.0/jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar)
>   to method
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int)
>
> ## Created at 2019-11-13T19:35:46.205 WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of
>
> com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector
>
> ## Created at 2019-11-13T19:35:46.212 WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
>
> ## Created at 2019-11-13T19:35:46.222 WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

Answer (score 4):

You can try adding the following to the Maven Surefire Plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>
            --illegal-access=permit
        </argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If you are running with JDK 11.

Comment: This is my first time to touch this code, so I'm beginning to suspect that nobody ever took the time to migrate to JDK 11.  I probably need to review every dependency for JDK 11 as per https://winterbe.com/posts/2018/08/29/migrate-maven-projects-to-java-11-jigsaw/

Comment: If no one has bothered to go through the motion to confirm it is all working then switch back to a JDK 8 and it should all work just fine.

Comment: Which version of JAXB is used? This issue was fixed several years ago so I suspect you've ended up transitively depending an old version.

Comment: The issue is that someone needed functionality provided by surefire 3.0.0-M3, but that version is built for java 11 and nobody had bothered to update to a compatible version of spring boot.  I upgraded spring boot to 2.2.1.RELEASE and it resolved the issue.